# How to get number or string LUA

Tags: string, lua, match, matching

I try to get

```
34.121+16 QRL
```

from

```
Gangsters:  69 /recruit

Exp: 884.4B / 9.9M /boost

Cash: 34.121+16 QRL 
Gems: 0  /donate
```

but i dont know how. Hope some one can helpme

Comment: result

`34.121+16 QRL 
Gems: 0  /donate`

still cannot remove Gems: 0  /donate

Comment: `s:match"Cash:%s*([^\n]-)%s*"`

Comment: Also, s:match 'Cash:%s+(%S+%s+%S+)'

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
s:match("[\r\n]Cash:%s([%d.+]+%s%a+)")
```

See the [Lua online demo](https://ideone.com/a0cwUn)

The `match` method will return the captured text only as there is 1 capture group in the pattern.

- `[\r\n]` - a CR or LF
- `Cash:` - literal string `Cash:`
- `%s` - a whitespace
- `([%d.+]+%s%a+)` - Capture group:

  - `[%d.+]+` - 1+ digits, `.` or `+`
  - `%s` - a whitespace
  - `%a+` - 1+ letters